# Idiomatic ownership management of mutating state during arbitrary recursion in Rust

Tags: recursion, rust

I've just started playing around with Rust. I find it's ownership system really useful but I have a hard time understanding how to use it with arbitrary recursion, especially since Rust lacks guaranteed tail call optimisation.

Consider a function apply with the signature `apply(&str) -> (String, bool)`. It takes a string and deterministically returns a new string. For the purpose of this question we leave the implementation undefined. The function also returns a bool indicating "completion". We need to keep calling the function with the string it returns until the bool indicates completion. It is undefined how many calls it takes for us to get to completion. It could be 1, it could also be 1000000.

Since Rust does not have tail calls, doing this recursively would allocate an O(n) stack which could cause OOM. Since we can throw away the old string after the function has returned the new string, we only need constant memory. Therefore we need to do it in a loop:

```
fn apply(s: &str) -> (String, bool) {
    return ("xyz".to_string(), true); // Undefined implementation.
}

fn transform(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut im = s;
    loop {
        let (im_s, done) = apply(im);
        if done {
            return im_s;
        }
        im = &im_s
    }
}
```

However, compiling this will give the error `im_s does not live long enough`. Do I need to use some sort of runtime ownership checking or heap allocation mechanism to make this compile?

Comment: Today's awesome question title.

Comment: Note that you aren't actually doing any recursion - you even state you are deliberately avoiding recursion (for valid reasons).

Comment: @Shepmaster: A loop is just a less pure (imperative) way to express a recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your method, and ask "who owns the string when the loop iteration ends?":

```
fn transform(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut im = s;
    loop {
        let (im_s, done) = apply(im);
        if done {
            return im_s;
        }
        im = &im_s
    }
}
```

`im_s` owns the string, and then you take a reference to it. When the loop ends - *nothing owns the string*. That means that it will be dropped, which makes all existing references invalid. Since a dangling reference would allow you to break Rust memory safety guarantees, it's not allowed and you get the error you see.

The simplest fix is to simply always promote the input to a `String`:

```
fn transform(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut im = s.to_string();
    loop {
        let (im_new, done) = apply(&im);
        im = im_new;
        if done {
            return im;
        }
    }
}
```

Another fix is to use the delightfully-named [`Cow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) enum. This allows you to have either an owned or borrowed type:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn transform(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut im = Cow::Borrowed(s);
    loop {
        let (im_new, done) = apply(&im);
        im = Cow::Owned(im_new);
        if done { break }
    }
    im.into_owned()
}
```

Comment: The initial explanation was not needed but helpful for people reading this question. The combination of borrowed and owned memory made this tricky. The "simplest" fix you provided (own all the memory) is obviously ugly due to the unnecessary string copy. The Cow solution was definitely what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: So, in this case, what is Cow's generic type set to? `str`?

Comment: *The "simplest" fix you provided (own all the memory) is obviously ugly due to the unnecessary string copy* => Which copy? Beware of bringing your own preconceived notions in Rust, its use of move semantics *by default* is very much unlike any other language.

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson yes. You can verify this for yourself by tweaking the code to be `let mut im: () = Cow::Borrowed(s)`. This causes a type error that allows you to see what type was expected.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You can't arbitrarily/magically take ownership of a string without copying it. My experience from implementing a language similar to rust (aka. "preconceived notions"), allows me to just know such things. You can look at the to_string() implementation yourself if you don't believe me. https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/string.rs.html#1046

Comment: @HannesLandeholm: We may be suffering from language issues here, so I'll try to explain as best as I can... `to_string` is not about copying, it's about transforming: it transforms a `&str` (a slice into an existing buffer) into a `String` (an autonomous type holding onto a dynamically allocated buffer). You can move a `&str` without copying its content, you can move a `String` without copying its content, you can create a `&str` pointing into a `String` buffer without copying its content... but you cannot create a `String` from a `&str` without copying its content...

Comment: ... still, that's only 1 operation out of 4 that requires copying; all the others are cheap O(1) operations with no dynamic memory allocation (no matter the length of the content). So, yes, Rust does achieve moving without copying; I am not surprised you did not succeed previously, it's complicated, and Rust is maybe the first language implementing such complex tracking at compile-time (I know of no prior art for the Borrow Checker, only Region Management which is far from equivalent).

Comment: @MatthieuM. You claimed that to_string() did not copy memory. Where you right or wrong? Also I'm not going to go into a debate about semantics with you. I was *not* referring to moving ownership, I was referring to magically taking ownership of borrowed data. FYI, region based memory management is basically the same thing.

Comment: @HannesLandeholm: Ah! So that was my misunderstanding. I never tried to claim that `to_string` was not copying the content, however when you spoke of a "string copy" I thought that you were referring to a "copy" as in a duplication of an existing object (`String`, here). I did not think that using `to_string` in transform could be an issue seeing as you were yourself using it in `apply`... well, apologies for derailing the conversation :x

Comment: @HannesLandeholm: Back on topic, having `transform` and `apply` taking a `String` parameter instead of a `&str` one could be more efficient as they could grow the buffer of `String` in place rather than allocation new buffers each time.